# oracle second listener not work

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created two databases one called `test` and one that is called `archivio`. The `SID` is equals to `name`. I also created a listener for SID test that responds on port 1521 and one for the SID archivio that should answer on port 1522.

I have verified that the services are active

the first listener works properly. The second, reported to the archivio database, does not work. I perform the test using net manager. The error message is:

> *the listener is not currently aware of the service requested in connect descriptor*

with oracle sql developer i can connect to db `archivio` if i use local instead of base type connection

Other info:

> windows 7 ultimate oracle 12c

LISTNER.ORA

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Quest Shared\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = webgate1-PC)(PORT = 1522))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER1 = C:\app\cirom

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = webgate1-PC)(PORT = 1521))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\cirom
ADR_BASE_LISTENER1 = C:\app\cirom
```

TNSNAMES.ORA

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Quest Shared\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ARCHIVIO =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = webgate1-pc)(PORT = 1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = archivio)
    )
  )

LISTENER_TEST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ARCHIVIO =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))


TEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = webgate1-pc)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = test)
    )
  )
```

Comment: can you give the output of command "show parameter listener" form archivio database?

Comment: i get view or table not exists error.

Comment: Are you connected as sys or system user? you should obtain the following:
SQL> show parameter listener

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener                       string      LISTENER_1
remote_listener                      string      LISTENERS_1
SQL>

Comment: listener_networks                    string  /  local_listener                       string / remote_listener                      string  ....all empty

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an Oracle instance registered on a listener running on not default port (not TCP 1521) you have to configure the LOCAL_LISTENER parameter, for example:
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1522))

The command is:

```
alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1522))' scope=both;
```

Change hostname with you hostname.

Then restart you database or issue the command:

```
alter system register;
```

Giovanni

Comment: same result. can't connect and show parameter command show again empty value

Comment: @ciro: I edited the answer... can you try with scope=both instead of spfile? Did you get errors?